# Is the jay file format specific to Python datatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I can't find information on the `jay` file format mentioned [here](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html?highlight=jay#offloading-data).

Is it a datatable only format?

Comment: https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/1109

Comment: would accept if in answer form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jay file format was designed for datatable's use, and AFAIK is currently implemented by Python `datatable` only. That being said, there is nothing preventing this format to be later adopted by some other library or program.